# Intel Atom 330 Virtualisation

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, xenserver, central-processing-unit

I've been looking to virtualize my atom based server (This is the mobo: http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=A330ION). I've tried to install ESXi and it couldn't detect my hard drives, I've tried Xen Server but I couldn't install Windows due to no VT-x. So my question is, are there any other alternatives that I could use? All I need is to be able to install are linux distro's such as arch and ubuntu and a windows machine (xp will do).

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without VT-x support you really can´t run windows as a VM. Setting up Xen and running Debian or Ubuntu paravirtualized would probably work nicely, but the only way of getting windows into the mix would be to either run it (SLOWLY) via **qemu** or install windows on the machine itself and run for instance **Virtualbox** to handle the linux VMs. But even that would be far from optimal and probably very slow.

Without VT-x support, you really don't want to run any VMs without support for  paravirtualization. In other words, no windows.

Comment: Well I am trying to move from running Arch with virtualbox running a Windows guest.

Comment: Luke, Atom's aren't designed for this, give it up, it's a bad idea, use a proper processor.

Comment: I'm afraid Chopper3's got it - You're trying to run Crysis on a toaster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if A330 supports virtualization, but if it does you will need to enable it in BIOS. Also, make sure your SATA controller is running in AHCI mode, this way you will have better chances with VMware. Other then that I agree with @Chopper3 - give it up :-)

Answer (score 0):

well, i'm currently running virtualbox over a basic ubuntu server install. Its not as light as a standalone ESX I install but, well, it seems to work alright.

Answer (score 0):

without VT you're stuck with emulation and not proper virtualization. Still, virtualbox or vmware ws/player should work.